# Controlling a driverless USB Audio Device

Tags: audio, usb, hid

I have a USB audio device (Scarlett Focusrite 18i6) which does not require a driver, so I assume it uses the USB HID Audio Class standard.

It works on everything from Windows and Mac to Linux and iOS.

But on Mac and Windows, it has a control application which can for instance enable and disable direct monitoring.

How would I go about reverse-engineering how this is done, so that I can reproduce it on platforms where the control application does not exist?

I'm thinking of booting up Windows in a VMWare session and then logging the USB communication (somehow?) while using the control application, but it does sound tedious considering the amount of data and my very limited understanding of USB.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the control application using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) instead of reverse engineering it.  However, if it's accessing USB devices then there is a good chance it might be using an API not supported by Wine.

To reverse engineer it, you should find a way to look at the USB traffic between the computer and the device.  Total Phase has some [hardware USB protocol analyzers](http://www.totalphase.com/protocols/usb/), but you might be able to find a good software solution for free.

Comment: Yes, Wine would be a solution for an x86 Linux device, but I'm probably going to use it from a RPi and an iPhone, so it's not an option there.

Comment: There is a USB Sniffer project for Beagleboard at [link](http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010_Projects/USBSniffer)